# Constant communication on mdio bus is normal?

Tags: u-boot

I have several devices on mdio bus - 1 phy AR8035 and 3 Dual Phys DP83849ifvs. The mdio bus is controlled by AM335x SoC. The problem is that I can't get mdio access to AR8035 PHY, but DP83849ifvs mdio r/w is ok. I check it with help of u-boot 2020.07 (mdio read 0 2 command). DP83849ifvs has 0,1,2,3,8,9 PHYIDs (they are dual phys so 2 addresses on one IC), AR8035 has 4 PHYID. When I try to read it with mdio read 4 2 I get Error. I wanted to look closely on MDIO frame via oscilloscope but I found strange behavior on MDIO bus - there are a lot of frames non stop, ~100us between them. I wonder is it normal behavior for MDIO bus assuming I am in u-boot environment? Maybe AR8035 was damaged, went crazy and now flooding the bus? Thanks!

Comment: Also at first I made a mistake and assign the same PHYIDs on both DP83849ifvs and AR8035 and they start to transmitt simultaneously, can that damage the device?

Comment: MDIO interface runs at low frequency, so it should be easy to catch the entire frame via oscilloscope and know what the frame is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I know I'm doing it right now. It is just strange that the communication is not stopping... I thought that driver/u-boot only reads the PHYID regs at boot time to attach the right driver and then the communication stops... I'll try to investigates the frames...

Comment: I used to modify the ethernet driver from our software team, and debugged the GMAC module on my own (I design ASICs). When opening ether device, we'll first repeatedly read phy register to check if autonegotiation has done. But with time out mechanism, it's impossible for the read to go on endlessly...

Comment: I've analyzed the frames and It seems that u-boot constantly reads Basic Mode Status Register for all PHYIDs again and again, so maybe it's normal behavior... On the PHYID 4 there is no response, so I think my IC is  damaged...

Comment: By the way MDIO pin on AR8035 is open drain. I have pull-ups but maybe I also should configure open drain on SoC?

Comment: I don't think it's a must.